How to check the running applications in the background
I have an Android application lets say A.
All I want is to check if Application B is running in the background.
If it is not, I want to launch B application.
Here is my code:
private const val APPLICATION = "com.example.myapp"

class AppLauncher @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext val context: Context
) {

    fun launchApplication() {
        when {
            !isInstalled() -> throw ApplicationNotInstalledException()
            !isAppRunning() -> launchApplicationB()
        }
    }

    private fun launchApplicationB() {
        val launchIntent: Intent? =
            context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(APPLICATION)
        if (launchIntent != null) {
            context.startActivity(launchIntent)
        }
    }

    private fun isInstalled( ): Boolean {
        return try {
            context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(
                APPLICATION,
                PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES
            )
            true
        } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
            false
        }
    }


    private fun isAppRunning(): Boolean {
        val activityManager = context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager

        val runningProcesses = activityManager.runningAppProcesses
        for (process in runningProcesses) {
            if (process.processName == APPLICATION) {
                 return process.importance != ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND

            }
        }
        return false
    }
}

The problem lies at isAppRunning function:
 val runningProcesses = activityManager.runningAppProcesses

returns only one instance, the instance of the current application A.
How can I get ALL The running applications in foreground and background?

Generally, you cannot get that on modern versions of Android, for privacy and security reasons.

This question is similar to: Android 5.1.1 and above - getRunningAppProcesses() returns my application package only. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please find the answer below
import android.app.ActivityManager
import android.content.Context

fun getRunningApps(context: Context): List<String> {
val activityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
val runningAppProcesses = activityManager.runningAppProcesses
val runningApps = mutableListOf<String>()

for (processInfo in runningAppProcesses) {
    runningApps.add(processInfo.processName)
}
return runningApps
}

val runningApps = getRunningApps(context)
runningApps.forEach { appName ->
println("Running app: $appName")
}

